# Getting Invalid keystore format when running Springboot Application

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, jks

Trying to use https for my springboot application and followed the below steps:

1. Created the keystore for the certificate and generated Private Key:

   ```
    keytool -genkey -keysize 2048 -keyalg RSA -alias tomcat -keystore keystore.jks
   ```
2. Generated the CSR with above keytool and private key

   ```
    keytool -certreq -alias tomcat -file your.csr -keystore keystore.jks
   ```
3. Recived and install certificate on server succesfully

   ```
    keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias tomcat -file certificate.p7b -keystore keystore.jks -storepass ******
   ```
4. Configured the application with the below:

   ```
    server.port=8443
    server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
    server.ssl.key-store=/path/certificate.p7b
    server.ssl.key-store-password=******
    server.ssl.key-alias=tomcat
    server.ssl.enabled=true
   ```

However I keep getting `java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format` when I try to run the application.

Am I using the wrong store key type?
Do I have to use PKCS12 insted of JKS as keystore type?

Comment: **That's the wrong file.** `certificate.p7b` is NOT a keystore; it is the CA response file. Your keystore file is `keystore.jks`; use that. Also if you are on j9 or higher your keystore is not JKS it is PKCS12 -- but that's okay because j9 and up can read _either_ PKCS12 or JKS interchangeably. But this is not programming or development.

Comment: Try server.ssl.key-store=/path/keystore.jks